# Font-Size in HTML Email via Gmail

Tags: css, gmail, html-email

Has anyone ever experienced a problem that, when a font-size style is applied to an element, the Gmail client isn't consistent when rendering? Example, I set the font-size to 17px and everything renders as too big, and then I set it to 16px and it becomes radically smaller.

Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `pt` instead of `px` for *font-sizes*, seem to work for me.

Comment: I ended up using pt to set my font-size and decreasing my margin just in case it felt like overflowing. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Wow !! this is the perfect answer and saved my day !! I don't know why people down voted this :(

Answer (score 1):

Are you making e-mail templates?

Then you should use good-old-back-to-basics font tag:

```
<font size="2">text</font>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like they are overriding font-sizes and ignoring !important for text tags (a, p, etc)

When I applied the `font-size` to a wrapping `<td>` it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same issue today.
I didn't find an answer on this thread that helped me personally.

However, I resolved it by surrounding all the ill-behaved text paras with a span that had inline style like this

```
<span style="color:#613400;font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;font-family:Calibri,Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;">TEXT</span>
```

I realised later that even when I give font-size:14px!important; font didn't stick to the visible 14px size (Browser's element inspector showed it was 14px!), and the reason was probably that font-family was set different for that ill-behaving text. When I added font-family selector to the span, things started working fine.

This same style when applied to  or  as a whole didn't work.
What I found as a solution was that you should style all the text with span surrounding it.

Hope this helps someone who stumble on this thread!