# font-style and font-size not working in HTML email sent to Gmail

Tags: html, css, gmail, phpmailer, html-email

I can't get `font-style: italic` and `font-size:11px` to show properly in Gmail with a HTML formatted email. Why?

```
<p style="font-size: 11px; font-style: italic; line-height: 1.5; word-break: break-word; text-align: center; mso-line-height-alt: 21px; margin: 0;">
    <span style="font-size: 11px; font-style: italic; color: #2C3E50;">Some countries and/or payment systems are not yet supported for buy and cash-out functions.<br>Please read our <a href="https://test.com/faq/?Display_FAQ=1984">FAQ</a> for more information.</span>
</p>
```

What I see in the browser when opening the HTML directly (GOOD):
[image]

What I see in Gmail (NOT GOOD):
[image]

I validated the HTML with http://premailer.dialect.ca/ and it doesn't say anything is wrong in this regard. I checked many answers on Stackoverflow but none helped: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12325970/1181261), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28748629/1181261)

---

I am sending the email using [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). On server, we use [ssmtp](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSMTP) for dispatching email. Here is the PHPMailer code:

```
function send_email($address, $subject, $email_template_path) { 
    require '/home/composer/vendor/autoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true); // true` enables exceptions

    try {
        //Server settings
        // $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      // Enable verbose debug output
        $mail->isSMTP();                         
        $mail->Host       = 'mail.smth.net';    
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                
        $mail->Username   = 'mailer@domain.com';
        $mail->Password   = 'some&pas3eWer';   
        $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
        $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above

        //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom('info@mydomain.com', 'Info');
        $mail->addAddress($address);
        $mail->addReplyTo('support@mydomain.com', 'Support');

        // Attachments
        // $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
        // $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name

        // Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body    = file_get_contents($email_template_path); // see  https://pastebin.com/raw/WUhap2DQ

        $mail->send();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
    }
}
```

Comment: There is an unterminated padding-bottom in your p element style - I can't think that is the problem, but just maybe it's upset GMail sufficiently for it to ignore the whole setting? Also there are some settings in there that GMail doesn't I think support, does that cause it to abandon the whole style setting?

Comment: I see; I fixed it hoping this is the cause, but there is no difference.

Comment: Your updated code works for me. Gmail definitely removes entire `style` attributes if there's something it doesn't like in it. Feel free to post your entire code if this still doesn't work.

Comment: @HTeuMeuLeu here is the full HTML: https://pastebin.com/raw/WUhap2DQ

Comment: @PrimožKralj This code works fine for me in Gmail's desktop webmail. I used [Putsmail](https://www.putsmail.com) to send the email. How are you sending your email?

Comment: @HTeuMeuLeu I have added PHPMailer code.

Comment: Primož Kralj - I deleted my answer below since it is not related to PHPMailer. I tried replicating your code and it is working just fine. Have you tried using $mail->MsgHTML()?

Comment: Thanks for your input @NikkoJ. I will try with the proposed function. I think I will need to do more tests with other email providers to see if this is Google specific and why it happens. Maybe it's something with our ssmtp linux config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with improperly formatted code. In one of the `style=...` I was missing a `;`.